# T-SQL - Update field

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2.

How can I update a field as below:

```
""AUGUSTO NETO"" <augusto@uol.com>
""ANTONIO FAUSTINO"" <faustino@bol.com>
""ANDRE FORTINO"" <fortino@gmail.com>
""ADAUTO NETO"" <adauto@hotmail.com>
```

to

```
augusto@uol.com
faustino@bol.com
fortino@gmail.com
adauto@hotmail.com
```

I know how to remove some characters already:

```
update myTable set [E-mail]=REPLACE([E-MAIL],'""','') WHERE [E-MAIL] LIKE '%@%'
update myTable set [E-mail]=REPLACE([E-MAIL],'<','') WHERE [E-MAIL] LIKE '%@%'
update myTable set [E-mail]=REPLACE([E-MAIL],'>','') WHERE [E-MAIL] LIKE '%@%'
```

Does anyone knows how can I resolve it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you write code... we don't do that for you. you write the code, we'll (maybe) try help fix it. hint: you'll probably need to use [string functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/ms181984.aspx)

Comment: any tries? Just provide you a code?

Comment: If you provide food, I'll provide code.

Comment: I can just give you a good hint where to start. Get the position of < and > symbols and use Substring function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should do it:

Just replace `YourColumn` with the actual column name, and `YOURTABLE` with the actual table name

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(YourColumn, CHARINDEX('<', YourColumn), LEN(YourColumn)), '<', ''), '>', '')
FROM   YOURTABLE;
```